# match multiple numbers in sql and get count of all matches in rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 rows in sql:

```
sno        ids
1.         5,6,7
2.         6,8
3.         5,7,8
```

I would like to know how many users have max match of (5,6,7) in them for eg: ,`Sno. 2` has 1 and `Sno 3` has 2 and so on.Is there a query/way to do that or its not possible?

Comment: Is the `ids` column defined as a varchar? Does it contain the IDs separated with commas? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Yes its varchar and its seperated by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'd highly recommend normalizing your database (i.e. not storing comma delimited strings in a colum), here's one option using `case` and `find_in_set`:

```
select sno, 
  case when find_in_set(5, ids) then 1 else 0 end +
  case when find_in_set(6, ids) then 1 else 0 end +
  case when find_in_set(7, ids) then 1 else 0 end cnt
from yourtable
group by sno
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8967d1/2)

Comment: I there a way to dynamically do this :::::::: `case when find_in_set(5, ids) then 1 else 0 end +`   :::::::: I have many numbers so ,I was wondering if thats possible?Thanks